# d3 .csv with a lot of data, draw just for one month

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm using d3 to generate a bar chart, I have some CSV data with data for each day of 2015 with 4 columns.

- Date
- Bar 1
- Bar 2
- Line

The thing I want to achieve is that to represent just 12 bars for bar 1 and bar 2 and add a line over them (which I know how to do).

So can someone explain to me how to display bars just for the first of the month and not each day without changing the data?

Comment: do you want to display average of month as 1 bar ? or mean, median ?

Comment: average of the month, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nest` feature of `d3` will be helpful for you. It works as follows: give a key to each entry in your table (here the key is the month), and run a function for each bunch of entries having the same keys (here, take the average of Bar A and Bar B). This gives a table `key -> value`.

I'm assuming your date is represented as a standard string "yyyy-mm-dd"

```
var monthdata = d3.nest()
 .key(function(d) { 
     //get month from data (first 7 characters):
     return d.date.substring(0,7);})
 .rollup(function(d) { 
   //run this function where d is a set of entries with same month
   return {
        bar1: d3.sum(d, function(g) {return g.bar1; }) / d.length, //average of bar1
        bar2: d3.sum(d, function(g) {return g.bar2; }) / d.length //average of bar2
   }
 })
 .entries(csv_data);
```

at this point, `monthdata` should have the following form:

```
  [{ key: "2015-01", values: {bar1: 123.4, bar2: 32.10} },
   { key: "2015-02", values: {bar1: 1234, bar2: 132.10} },
    .. ]
```

... all ready to be plugged into a d3 bar chart.

Comment: [Bonus] A very nice link to test nesting functions: http://bl.ocks.org/shancarter/raw/4748131/